# Operations with truncation error

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion, error-propagation

Assume I'm given an equation  $a\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}$. I approximate $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}$ using a truncated taylor series to first order, such that the error is $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2)$. I then approximate $\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}$ using a truncated taylor series to second order, such that the error is $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^3)$.

How does the truncation error behave when adding the two terms? Does the $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2)$ error from the first term impact the $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2)$ from the second term? Do the coefficients still get multiplied by the truncation error in these operations? What about if the orginal equation involved multiplication? Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to work with the truncation error when I have polynomials of different degrees. The error plays an important role in my analysis, so I have to be sure I carry it trough with the operations. Any good references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $\Delta x\rightarrow 0$, $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2)+\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^3)=\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2)$.

Of course, this is just short form for the following: let $f$ be in $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2)$ and $g$ be in $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^3)$. Then, $f+g=h$ where $h$ is an element of $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2)$. However, this is cumbersome to write, so we use the above instead.

You should really read about [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: Assume $\Delta x$ does not go to zero. Assume it's greater than 1. I just say that cause I don't know if I can assume that...it's applied to numerical analysis and it's rare that $\Delta x$ is less than 1

Comment: Also, one other thing... is $a*\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2) + b*\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2) = (a+b)*\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2)$ ? I understand that the coefficients can be absorbed if they're of lesser order, but the coefficients still give some information about the error, no?

Comment: "Big O" stands for something *totally* different. Jus saying.

Comment: @A.S. Can you elaborate more? I'm not sure if that is directed at me or par's answer. Can you provide a better answer to my question?

Comment: I think trying to guess the way this works is not going to get you very far. You should read the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Since when is asking a question considered guessing? You might as well answer every question on here with "see wikipedia" if that's your position. I appreciate your answer and I didn't argue against it. Besides, you started your answer with "assume" so who's guessing? I'm just trying to build my understanding with supporting questions...I don't think that's too much to ask.

Comment: Not at all, and I did not mean it to sound hostile. My meaning was that it sounds like you should seek the formal definition of Big O at this point. Without it, you'll only be able to call upon identities like the one above, without knowing why it holds. Sorry, and best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You already have received a good answer from @par.

Let me make this more simple : you measure the length $L_A$ of stick $A$ with an accuracy of $1$ inch and the length $L_B$ of stick $B$ with an accuracy of $0.1$ inch.

Answer the question : what is the accuracy for $L_A+L_B$ ? $1$ inch, isn't it ?

This is very similar to your problem $O\left(x^1\right)+O\left(x^2\right)=O\left(x^1\right)$

Comment: Thank you for the practical example...always refreshing!